# Displaying custom html in form.io grid view (dynamic CSS class)

Tags: angularjs, formio

I'm trying to set up a form.IO form that will let me use the value of a field as part of the css class. This needs to take effect when the item is in the table view. If it also influences the form view that's ok because we don't have the element showing in the form view.

Specifically I want to get the following output:

`<div class="[value]Stoplight">&nbsp;</div>`

The values from the object are going to be colors e.g. "yellow" so the result would be:

`<div class="yellowStoplight">&nbsp;</div>`

Once I have that I can have my CSS file specify a background image based on the class and make it display the way I want.

Alternatively if I could put an html element of type image and have the source be different based on the value of the object that would work too.

Any ideas on how I could make either of those work? I'm not finding anything that relates to "dynamic css". Perhaps I'm looking for the wrong search criteria.

Comment: The answer to this is different dependent on what framework you are using. Angular 1 or Angular 2+?

Comment: I think angular 1. I have since found out we are using a different grid control to display the table. This issue was resolved. Thanks anyway.